# Javascript RegEx replacing &quot;

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to patch the Drupal Panels module to fix [this nasty issue](http://drupal.org/node/1124042), which makes the AJAX errorhandler completely unreadable. The error handler has this:

```
// Replace all &lt; and &gt; by < and >
  error_text = error_text.replace("/&(lt|gt);/g", function (m, p) { 
    return (p == "lt")? "<" : ">";
  });
```

I've tried two approaches:

Adding

```
// Now replace all &quot with ' for readability, for goodness sakes, per
  // http://drupal.org/node/1124042
  error_text = error_text.replace(/&quot;/g, "'");
```

Modifying

```
// Replace all &lt; and &gt; by < and >
  error_text = error_text.replace("/&(lt|gt|quot);/g", function (m, p) { 
    return (p == "lt")? "<" : (p == "gt") ? ">" : "'";
  });
```

Yet neither has worked. Little help?

EDIT: When printed out to console (in FF4 or Chrome) The HTML entities are not shown. The resulting alert(""), however, looks like so:

```
An error occurred at /home/panels/ajax/editor/select-content/panel_context%3Apage-faculty_page%3Apage_faculty_page_panel_context/center.

Error Description: [ { &quot;command&quot;: &quot;settings&quot;, &quot;argument&quot;: {    &quot;basePath&quot;: &quot;/home/&quot;, &quot;admin_menu&quot;: { &quot;margin_top&quot;: 1 }, &quot;asu_webauth&quot;: { &quot;callapp&quot;:
>&quot;home&quot;, quot;onLogoutURL&quot;: &quot;http://physics-dev.asu.edu&quot; } } }, { &quot;command&quot;: &quot;css_files&quot;, &quot;argument&quot;: [ { &quot;file&quot;: &quot;/home/modules/node/node.css?E&quot;, &quot;media&quot;: &quot;all&quot; }, { &quot;file&quot;: &quot;/home/modules/system/defaults.css?E&quot;, &quot;media&quot;: &quot;all&quot; }, { &quot;file&quot;: &quot;/home/modules/system/system.css?E&quot;, &quot;media&quot;: &quot;all&quot; }, { &quot;file&quot;: &quot;/home/modules/system/system-menus.css?E&quot;, &quot;media&quot;: &quot;all&quot; }, { &quot;file&quot;: &quot;/home/modules/user/user.css?E&quot;, &quot;media&quot;: &quot;all&quot; }, { &quot;file&quot;: &quot;/home/sites/all/modules/admin_menu/admin_menu.css?E&quot;, &quot;media&quot;: &quot;all&quot; }, { &quot;file&quot;: &quot;/home/sites/all/modules/cck/theme/content-module.css?E&quot;, &quot;media&quot;: &quot;all&quot; }, { &quot;file&quot;: &quot;/home/sites/all/modules/ctools/css/ctools.css?E&quot;, &quot;media&quot;: &quot;all&quot; }, { &quot;file&quot;: &quot;/home/sites/all/modules/date/date.css?E&quot;, &quot;media&quot;: &quot;all&quot; }, { &quot;file&quot;: &quot;/home/sites/all/modules/filefield/filefield.css?E&quot;, &quot;media&quot;: &quot;all&quot; }, { &quot;file&quot;: &quot;/home/sites/all/modules/office_hours/office_hours.css?E&quot;, &quot;media&quot;: &quot;all&quot; }, { &quot;file&quot;: &quot;/home/sites/all/modules/og/theme/og.css?E&quot;, &quot;media&quot;: &quot;all&quot; }, { &quot;file&quot;: &quot;/home/sites/all/modules/panels/css/panels.css?E&quot;, &quot;media&quot;: &quot;all&quot; }, { &quot;file&quot;: &quot;/home/sites/all/modules/views_slideshow/contrib/views_slideshow_singleframe/views_slideshow.css?E&quot;, &quot;media&quot;: &quot;all&quot; }, { &quot;file&quot;: &quot;/home/sites/all/modules/views_slideshow/contrib/views_slideshow_thumbnailhover/views_slideshow.css?E&quot;, &quot;media&quot;: &quot;all&quot; }, { &quot;file&quot;: &quot;/home/misc/farbtastic/farbtastic.css?E&quot;, &quot;media&quot;: &quot;all&quot; }, { &quot;file&quot;: &quot;/home/sites/all/modules/calendar/calendar.css?E&quot;, &quot;media&quot;: &quot;all&quot; }, { &quot;file&quot;: &quot;/home/sites/all/modules/cck/modules/fieldgroup/fieldgroup.css?E&quot;, &quot;media&quot;: &quot;all&quot; }, { &quot;file&quot;: &quot;/home/sites/all/modules/views/css/views.css?E&quot;, &quot;media&quot;: &quot;all&quot; } ] }, { &quot;command&quot;: &quot;scripts&quot;, &quot;argument&quot;: [ &quot;/home/misc/jquery.js&quot;, &quot;/home/misc/drupal.js&quot;, &quot;/home/sites/all/modules/admin_menu/admin_menu.js&quot;, &quot;/home/sites/all/modules/og/og.js&quot;, &quot;/home/sites/all/modules/panels/js/panels.js&quot;, &quot;/home/sites/all/modules/views_slideshow/js/jquery.cycle.all.min.js&quot;, &quot;/home/sites/all/modules/views_slideshow/contrib/views_slideshow_singleframe/views_slideshow.js&quot;, &quot;/home/sites/all/modules/views_slideshow/contrib/views_slideshow_thumbnailhover/views_slideshow.js&quot;, &quot;/home/sites/all/modules/asu_webauth/asu_webauth.js&quot; ] }, { &quot;command&quot;: &quot;modal_display&quot;, &quot;title&quot;: &quot;Add content to Center&quot;, &quot;output&quot;: &quot;\x3cdiv class=\&quot;panels-add-content-modal\&quot;\x3e\x3cdiv class=\&quot;panels-section-column panels-section-column-categories\&quot;\x3e\x3cdiv class=\&quot;inside\&quot;\x3e\x3cdiv class=\&quot;panels-categories-box\&quot;\x3e\x3ca href=\&quot;/home/panels/ajax/editor/select-content/panel_context%3Apage-faculty_page%3Apage_faculty_page_panel_context/center/activity\&quot; class=\&quot;ctools-use-ajax panels-modal-add-category\&quot; title=\&quot;\&quot;\x3eActivity\x3c/a\x3e\x3ca href=\&quot;/home/panels/ajax/editor/select-content/panel_context%3Apage-faculty_page%3Apage_faculty_page_panel_context/center/menus\&quot; class=\&quot;ctools-use-ajax panels-modal-add-category\&quot; title=\&quot;\&quot;\x3eMenus\x3c/a\x3e\x3ca href=\&quot;/home/panels/ajax/editor/select-content/panel_context%3Apage-faculty_page%3Apage_faculty_page_panel_context/center/miscellaneous\&quot; class=\&quot;ctools-use-ajax panels-modal-add-category\&quot; title=\&quot;\&quot;\x3eMiscellaneous\x3c/a\x3e\x3ca href=\&quot;/home/panels/ajax/editor/select-content/panel_context%3Apage-faculty_page%3Apage_faculty_page_panel_context/center/page-elements\&quot; class=\&quot;ctools-use-ajax panels-modal-add-category\&quot; title=\&quot;\&quot;\x3ePage elements\x3c/a\x3e\x3ca href=\&quot;/home/panels/ajax/editor/select-content/panel_context%3Apage-faculty_page%3Apage_faculty_page_panel_context/center/view-panes\&quot; class=\&quot;ctools-use-ajax panels-modal-add-category\&quot; title=\&quot;\&quot;\x3eView panes\x3c/a\x3e\x3ca href=\&quot;/home/panels/ajax/editor/select-content/panel_context%3Apage-faculty_page%3Apage_faculty_page_panel_context/center/views\&quot; class=\&quot;ctools-use-ajax panels-modal-add-category\&quot; title=\&quot;\&quot;\x3eViews\x3c/a\x3e\x3ca href=\&quot;/home/panels/ajax/editor/select-content/panel_context%3Apage-faculty_page%3Apage_faculty_page_panel_context/center/widgets\&quot; class=\&quot;ctools-use-ajax panels-modal-add-category\&quot; title=\&quot;\&quot;\x3eWidgets\x3c/a\x3e\x3c/div\x3e\x3cdiv class=\&quot;content-type-button clear-block\&quot;\x3e\x3ca href=\&quot;/home/panels/ajax/editor/add-pane/panel_context%3Apage-faculty_page%3Apage_faculty_page_panel_context/center/node/node\&quot; class=\&quot;ctools-use-ajax panels-modal-add-config\&quot; title=\&quot;Add a node from your site as content.\&quot;\x3e\x3cimg src=\&quot;/home/sites/all/modules/ctools/plugins/content_types/node/icon_node.png\&quot; alt=\&quot;\&quot; title=\&quot;\&quot; width=\&quot;16\&quot; height=\&quot;16\&quot; /\x3e\x3c/a\x3e\x3cdiv\x3e\x3ca href=\&quot;/home/panels/ajax/editor/add-pane/panel_context%3Apage-faculty_page%3Apage_faculty_page_panel_context/center/node/node\&quot; class=\&quot;ctools-use-ajax panels-modal-add-config\&quot; title=\&quot;Add a node from your site as content.\&quot;\x3eExisting node\x3c/a\x3e\x3c/div\x3e\x3c/div\x3e\x3cdiv class=\&quot;content-type-button clear-block\&quot;\x3e\x3ca href=\&quot;/home/panels/ajax/editor/add-pane/panel_context%3Apage-faculty_page%3Apage_faculty_page_panel_context/center/custom/custom\&quot; class=\&quot;ctools-use-ajax panels-modal-add-config\&quot; title=\&quot;Create a completely custom piece of HTML content.\&quot;\x3e\x3cimg src=\&quot;/home/sites/all/modules/ctools/images/no-icon.png\&quot; alt=\&quot;\&quot; title=\&quot;\&quot; width=\&quot;16\&quot; height=\&quot;16\&quot; /\x3e\x3c/a\x3e\x3cdiv\x3e\x3ca href=\&quot;/home/panels/ajax/editor/add-pane/panel_context%3Apage-faculty_page%3Apage_faculty_page_panel_context/center/custom/custom\&quot; class=\&quot;ctools-use-ajax panels-modal-add-config\&quot; title=\&quot;Create a completely custom piece of HTML content.\&quot;\x3eNew custom content\x3c/a\x3e\x3c/div\x3e\x3c/div\x3e\x3c/div\x3e\x3c/div\x3e\x3cdiv class=\&quot;panels-categories-description\&quot;\x3eContent options are divided by category. Please select a category from the left to proceed.\x3c/div\x3e\x3c/div\x3e&quot; } ]
```

Comment: Properly, `&quot;` should be translated to `"`.  (`'` would be `&apos;`)

Comment: what drupal version are you using ?

Comment: 6.20 with Panels 6.x-3.9 and CTools  6.x-1.8. I think the deeper issue may be something else, as I was able to add Panels before and then "something happened" and now whenever I click on "Add content" in the Page Manager I get this type of error. That said, I still dislike that the CTools error handler doesn't "pretty print" the error message for the user (nor even wrote it out to console, until I just added that) so I was trying to do this as a service.

Comment: just glancing over the drupal code (*not a user myself*) you should patch the `Drupal.ahahError` method in the `drupal.js` file. But you need to change the last part where the message is returned `return message;` to `return message.replace(/&(lt|gt|quot);/g, function (m, p) { 
    return (p == "lt")? "<" : (p == "gt") ? ">" : "'";
  });`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

remove the quotes around the regex

```
  error_text = error_text.replace(/&(lt|gt|quot);/g, function (m, p) { 
    return (p == "lt")? "<" : (p == "gt") ? ">" : "'";
  });
```

**demo** http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/mfmkc/

Comment: Good job the with JSFiddle. This should work, and yet for some reason doesn't. The output remains as shown in the screenshot attached to the referenced issue.

Comment: @Visionary have you verified that the error is alerted from the function your are patching ? (*adding an additional alert would prove that*). Also try adding `console.log(error_text)` before alerting it and see what is printed in firebug.

Comment: Indeed, an alert above the line shows that it is reached. I assume the console automatically takes care of html entities, as it prints readably there but not in the alert.

Answer (score 10):

```
str.replace(/&(l|g|quo)t;/g, function(a,b){
    return {
        l   : '<',
        g   : '>',
        quo : '"'
    }[b];
})
```

Comment: This is like a miracle of code obfuscation. To save 1 character comparison (since t is common across gt; lt; quot;) we've managed to make the regex 500% more confusing. Good show.

Comment: Thank you, that was my goal!  :)  You can save 2 more if you take out the `?:` and 3 more beyond that if you take the `t` out of the match and then make it `{l:'<', ...`, [edit], okay just made those changes

Comment: +1 for the super clear property lookup instead of conditionals (or trinary, or case) but I agree the longer regex is more readable.  And if you're willing to shave a character in a regex shouldn't you care more about a closure on the anonymous object construction?

Comment: Well splitting the regex was really a joke :)  Fortunately the OP was smart enough to realize that

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
var str = '&lt;span&gt;&quot;error&quot;&lt;/span&gt;';
str.replace(/&(lt|gt|quot);/g, function(m, t) {
  switch (t) {
  case 'lt':
    return '<';
  case 'gt':
    return '>';
  case 'quot':
    return '\'';
  }
});
```

It returns `"<span>'error'</span>"`

If that's not working, then perhaps your original string contains `&amp;lt;` instead of `&lt;`, etc...

Comment: I doubt the ternary if statement is the problem, especially considering the provably correct solution below.

Comment: it explains why the second solution doesn't work (wrapped the regular expression literal in quotes) but still not sure why the first approach you took won't work, as its working for me.

Comment: It seems your code has typo. Order parameters in parameter list of function should be reversed: function(t, m).