# Getting wrong format '&quot;' instead of normal quotes (“”)

Tags: javascript

I am generating dynamic JavaScript using some web-service.

I am getting this result:

```
[{&quot;values&quot;: [{&quot;count&quot;: 1, &quot;text&quot;: &quot;Yes&quot;}, {&quot;count&quot;: 0, &quot;text&quot;: &quot;No&quot;}], &quot;key&quot;: &quot;Welcome?&quot;}];
```

What i want :

```
 [{"values": [{"count": 1, "text": "Yes"}, {"count": 0, "text": "No"}], "key": "Welcome?"}];
```

Currently i managed this with `.replace(/&amp;quot;/g,'"')`

But i want more proper solution if possible.

Thanks

Comment: How are you retrieving the response, what format? Looks like badly parsed JSON...

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are using html_entities on your json.

What I do is build up and array and then json_encode it.

```
<?php
    $data = array(
        "values" => array(
            array("count" => 1, "text" => "Yes"),
            array("count" => 0, "text" => "No"),
        ),
        "key" => "Welcome?"
    );

    $json_data = json_encode($data);
```

to get the exact same json as in your question just wrap the data array in another array:

```
<?php
    $data = array(
        array(
            "values" => array(
                array("count" => 1, "text" => "Yes"),
                array("count" => 0, "text" => "No"),
            ),
            "key" => "Welcome?"
        )
    );

    $json_data = json_encode($data);
```

Comment: I'm using simple JavaScript.
And the data coming from web services.

Comment: Sorry I assumed PHP because I've been bitten with the quotes thing... maybe have a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5957546/javascript-regex-replacing-quot